# iPhone OTA distribution

Tags: iphone, distribution

I tried to create OTA for my sample app by using the following link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

I created a tag with my url:
Install App 
but it gives an error:
Safari can’t open “itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://XXXX-XX/MobileApps/otatest.plist” because Microsoft Windows doesn’t recognize Internet addresses starting with “itms-services:”.

almost the same with internet explorer.

Do I need to add any thing in my server to reconize itms-services?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Malleswar

Answer (score 11):

You need to access to your URL with an iPhone, not a computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to access the .plist from iphone browser and desktop browser. It just shows the content. of xml file.

Comment: You don't load the plist in your browser, you have to click a link from an HTML file with the proper `itms-services://` link.

Comment: Make sure the MIME types are properly configured on the server. See here: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked with some server configuration. I will soon write the article on this and update the link.

Comment: hey how it worked in browser?i need to add itms url in browser and download the app

Comment: I have the same problem, can you please tell me what kind of configuration it needs from web server side