# Sinatra redirect to URI without path

Tags: ruby, redirect, sinatra

I'm trying a simple redirect to an OTA installation link for iOS of the pattern:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist
```

Regardless of the tried redirect method Sinatra (webrick?) however always complains about an invalid URI: `ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(absolute but no path):`

I already tried the following calls:

```
# Simple redirect
redirect 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist'

# Raw headers redirect
status 302
headers 'Location' => 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist'

# Halt redirect
halt 302, { 'Location' => 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist' }, ''
```

always resulting in the same error.

Is there any possibility to do a redirect without triggering the parsing of URI class?

(Sinatra 1.4.3, Ruby 1.9.3p194)

Comment: Have you tried using `send_file`?  http://alfuken.tumblr.com/post/874428235/upload-and-download-files-in-sinatra

Comment: Thanks for your approach, send_file however does only deal with paths imho, I would need a real browser redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with a work-around which also works on Webrick, this snippet however disables URI path checks at all:

```rb
# Add empty pattern for URI hostname parsing to allow itms-services://? URIs
module URI
  def self.parse(uri)
    URI::Parser.new(:HOSTNAME => "(?:)|(?:#{::URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::HOSTNAME})").parse(uri)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's the response that is the problem, it's the subsequent request. The error is raised by the URI library, because the uri *does* look invalid. [Sinatra doesn't parse the uri](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L249) and [WEBrick only parses the *requests* using URI](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/webrick/httprequest.rb#L447).

You need to provide a uri that a webserver can use, one without a hostname that has the scheme is unlikely to be parsed as valid or usable.

From [the RFC - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> For example, the "file" URI
> scheme is defined so that no authority, an empty host, and
> "localhost" all mean the end-user's machine, whereas the "http"
> scheme considers a missing authority or empty host invalid.

It's an HTTP server, so you'll have to help it out - see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125089/iphone-ota-distribution/4284978)

---

As an example of what I've mentioned here and in the comments below, that Sinatra sends headers via redirect and the webserver shouldn't be parsing URI's in a response, in an IRB session:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
# => false
class BadUri < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
      redirect 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist'
    end
  end
# => [Az, [], [], #<Proc:0x000001009c50a8@/Users/iainuser/RubyProjects/Test/SO19858178/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1593>]
BadUri.run!
[2013-11-11 14:18:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-11-11 14:18:42] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-06) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-11-11 14:18:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=36540 port=4567
```

and then getting the response:

```
curl -D headers http://localhost:4567/
```

and in the `headers` file it dumped:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Location: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://builds.net/abc.plist
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 0
```

No errors thrown. But that was with Puma. I tried it with Thin… it worked too. With Webrick, it throws an error, so **don't use Webrick**.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I would then however still see the problem with URI class, the webserver should be capable of sending raw response headers. Probably it's possible to provide a custom subclass of generic.rb for the itms-services scheme?

Comment: @alexleutgoeb The webserver *does* send the headers properly. If you look at the Sinatra source (see the link) that's exactly how it deals with a redirect. What's happening is after receipt of that header, the browser (or whatever client you're using, but I'm guessing it's a browser because of this behaviour) is following the location header, making a request, and it's *this request* that gets parsed. The URI is just not valid, as far as I can see.

Comment: @alexleutgoeb Actually, thinking about this some more, I'm not even sure how the server is seeing this URI *because the client wouldn't know where to send it*. If you're calling `halt` and that throws an error then that suggests that the server is parsing the response headers, which all sounds very wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigations, I upvoted your answer and added my current workaround as additional answer, I'm however not quite sure which one's the better "accepted answer" of these two atm. ;)

Comment: @alexleutgoeb no probs, glad to help. That'll work too, though since it's unlikely you'll be using Webrick in production you may as well switch over to a better server.

Comment: Valid point, production environment runs over unicorn, dev and especially test are Webrick unfortunately, so I will need this one for passing tests. Thanks again!